# detect screen size on iPhone match to IOS 14 and above

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, typescript

I am try to find screen height size on my mobile devices
I am trying to do `window.screen.height` but it work only on android devices and windows.
I need something new that match to IOS devices with version 14 and above, see a lot of ways to do it on internet but nothing work.

it should work an detect on every iPhone screen
like

```
if(window.screen.height>450)
  something..
else
  something..
```

Thanks for helping guys and have a good day!

Comment: Angular's CDK offers responsive layout utils to help you do custom logic based on a screen size https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview . What do you mean by "match to IOS devices with version 14 and above" though, what does that have to do with screen size?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no my friend I don't use jQuery in my website and all another response I already used

Comment: @Alex hi, I don't know about that on Angular it support IOS media query? if yes i'll try it

Comment: @LichayTiram did you read all the answers? There are many that don't use jquery

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes i am find a solution was low comment thanks